# CCParticleSystem removal best practices

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

My question is for apps written in cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b for ios:

**What** are the **best practices** for **removing/releasing** a **CCParticleSystem**?

One way I know of is using setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES.

```
[emitter setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES];
[emitter stopSystem];
```

Another way is removing the emitter manually using removeChild.

Are there any others? Which way is usually recommended?

As a side note, are there any known issues regarding CCParticleSystem removal/release under cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a particle system, just remove it from its parent node. It's the best way.

If your particle system doesn't have a infinite duration, the best way is use `setAutoRemoveOnFinish`. It will automatically remove the system from parent node when particle system ends.

If your particle system have a infinite duration, then use `removeChild` with `cleanUp:YES` (you dont need to set `stopSystem before`). This way the system is removed forced.

Or you can use `stopSystem` with `setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES`, and the system will be removed after the last particle ends. This way the system is removed smoothly.

Other tips:

- Use `CCParticleSystemQuad` instead of `CCParticleSystem`.
- Is recommended that you create your particle system using an `autorelease` constructor, like `[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:]` or `[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithTotalParticles:]`.
- And, of course, use `release` if you have a property retaining it.

Comment: are you sure this is correct? "stopSystem won't remove the particle system. It will stop it, but the system will remains as child. IMPORTANT: If you stop the system, it will not be removed by setAutoRemoveOnFinish, because it is stopped and will not finish."

Comment: Yes! 'stopSystem' will "pause" the system. And it can be restarted again with 'resetSystem'.

Comment: I looked into it and it seems likes this is not true, since the emitter does get removed.
I saw in the ccparticlesystem code that the condition for removal using the autoRemoveOnFinish property is:
if( particleCount == 0 && autoRemoveOnFinish_ ).

stopSystem would make the particleCount to be 0 after a few seconds (depending on the particle lifespan, as no more particles will be emitted). I think this is supposed to be the way to remove an emitter in a "nice" way, animation-wise (it will look better than to "yank" out the particle system, along with all living particles, with removeChild).

Comment: Sorry, i looked at the CCParticleSystem code and you're right! stopSystem will remove the particle system after lifespan of the last particle. I've edited the answer. Thanks!